# Media Queries: Google Map not displaying right on window resize

Tags: css, google-maps, media-queries

I am using an adaptive layout on my site by using media queries.

Now when I resize the browser window past a certain media query, the **google map displays faulty (see image)**

What I do:

CSS:

```
#googleMap2{display: none;}

@media screen and (min-width: 919px){
   #googleMap{display: none;}
   #googleMap2{display: block;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="googleMap">[google-map-v3 width="920" height="550" .......]</div>
<div id="googleMap2">[google-map-v3 width="768" height="320" .......]</div>
```

[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the map know it's been resized:

```
google.maps.event.trigger( map, 'resize' );
```

Call this on the resize event for your page or container.

With this approach you can use a single map and resize it as needed, instead of having to switch between two or more fixed size maps.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/rDnmq/1/) has a working example. I don't know what the rest of your page layout will look like, but to illustrate one common layout I put a top bar and sidebar in the page, with the map filling the remaining space on the bottom right. Try resizing the page and you will see it in action.

Comment: How do i call this? from a normal <script> tag? Or do I call it from within the google map html code I specified here? No I use two maps: I show and hide them depending on the viewport dimensions. I do that because is the best way I know how to resize the map when the viewport changes...Do you have a better solution? I want to make the map responsive, and height: 100% does not work with google maps

Comment: Sure, let me give you a more concrete example. I'll post it within the hour. It will use a single map div that resizes automatically to fill the available space. It won't use fixed size steps but will simply resize to fit. You could of course impose fixed size steps on top of that, but in most cases it's nicer to let the map fill a space exactly. One question: are you using jQuery? The sample code I have handy uses it, but it would be easy enough to change it to straight DOM code if necessary.